# Flash Drive not appearing in Disks utility, and not mounting

Tags: mount, usb-drive, drive

As it says on the tin, I have [flash drive](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B014W4MRZK) that a few days ago worked just fine, but now will neither mount, nor be recognized by the Disks utility. I have no idea why this is happening, but I want to fix it. The contents of the drive are disposable, so no worries for that. I have Ubuntu 16.04LTS 64-bit.

Edit: It was asked about the output of `dmesg|tail -50`, which is below

```
[56868.407682] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[56868.412174] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[56868.416116] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[56868.876250] [drm] ib test on ring 2 succeeded in 0 usecs
[56868.876354] [drm] ib test on ring 3 succeeded in 0 usecs
[56868.876434] [drm] ib test on ring 4 succeeded in 0 usecs
[56869.396256] [drm] ib test on ring 5 succeeded
[56869.417109] [drm] ib test on ring 6 succeeded
[56869.417950] [drm] ib test on ring 7 succeeded
[56871.519812] [drm] probing gen 2 caps for device 1022:1425 =733d01/e
[56871.519817] [drm] enabling PCIE gen 3 link speeds, disable with radeon.pcie_gen2=0
[56872.997201] [drm] PCIE GART of 2048M enabled (table at 0x0000000000040000).
[56872.997366] radeon 0000:01:00.0: WB enabled
[56872.997370] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c00 and cpu addr 0xffff8800352b8c00
[56872.997373] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 1 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c04 and cpu addr 0xffff8800352b8c04
[56872.997375] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 2 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c08 and cpu addr 0xffff8800352b8c08
[56872.997378] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c0c and cpu addr 0xffff8800352b8c0c
[56872.997380] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 4 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c10 and cpu addr 0xffff8800352b8c10
[56872.997383] radeon 0000:01:00.0: VCE init error (-22).
[56873.419752] [drm] ring test on 0 succeeded in 1 usecs
[56873.419758] [drm] ring test on 1 succeeded in 1 usecs
[56873.419765] [drm] ring test on 2 succeeded in 1 usecs
[56873.419777] [drm] ring test on 3 succeeded in 4 usecs
[56873.419784] [drm] ring test on 4 succeeded in 4 usecs
[56873.419908] [drm] ib test on ring 0 succeeded in 0 usecs
[56873.419951] [drm] ib test on ring 1 succeeded in 0 usecs
[56873.419991] [drm] ib test on ring 2 succeeded in 0 usecs
[56873.420040] [drm] ib test on ring 3 succeeded in 0 usecs
[56873.420060] [drm] ib test on ring 4 succeeded in 0 usecs
[56873.448640] PM: resume of devices complete after 5778.716 msecs
[56873.453722] PM: Finishing wakeup.
[56873.453724] Restarting tasks ... done.
[56873.480410] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=8723
[56873.480416] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
[56873.482216] Bluetooth: hci0: rom_version status=0 version=1
[56873.735190] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp4s0: link is not ready
[56874.437221] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp4s0: link is not ready
[56874.439141] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
[56874.450159] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link down
[56874.450256] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
[56874.562416] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp4s0: link is not ready
[56876.296340] wlp4s0: authenticate with 3c:8c:f8:83:e8:0c
[56876.326261] wlp4s0: send auth to 3c:8c:f8:83:e8:0c (try 1/3)
[56876.353559] wlp4s0: authenticated
[56876.356213] wlp4s0: associate with 3c:8c:f8:83:e8:0c (try 1/3)
[56876.382707] wlp4s0: RX AssocResp from 3c:8c:f8:83:e8:0c (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=3)
[56876.385118] wlp4s0: associated
[56876.385140] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp4s0: link becomes ready
[56906.414545] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp4s0 OUT= MAC=40:b8:9a:84:d6:8f:3c:8c:f8:83:e8:0c:08:00 SRC=192.168.10.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=50500 PROTO=2 
[56966.322162] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp4s0 OUT= MAC=40:b8:9a:84:d6:8f:3c:8c:f8:83:e8:0c:08:00 SRC=192.168.10.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=50514 PROTO=2
```

Comment: What is the output of `dmesg | tail -50` after you plug in the flash drive?

Comment: @stumblebee we're thinking the same thing...

Comment: @stumblebee See my edit

Comment: The drive is not being detected by the system. What happens if you use a different flash drive/USB port?

Comment: All ports don't work for this drive, but all are fine for another drive.

Comment: compare the output of "lsusb" before and after plugging the flash-drive in; try a different computer; maybe it's just dead.

Comment: "Iron man" has bit the dust then.